# boolean variables posted through AJAX being treated as strings in server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, boolean, post-processing

Following is a part of an AJAX functionality to add classes and packs to session cart:-

**The jquery part**

```
function addClassToCart(itemId)
{
   addItemToCart(itemId,true);
}

function addPackToCart(itemId)
{
   addItemToCart(itemId,false);
}

function addItemToCart(itemId,isClass)
{   
     $.post(url+"/ajax/add_cart", { operation: 'add_cart','isClass':isClass, 'itemId': itemId},
        function(data)
        {
               if(data.success)
               {
                      alert("item added to cart");
               }
        }, "json");

}
```

**The AJAX request processing php part -**

```
//Checking operation and other posted parameters
if($_POST['isClass'])
{
  //Code to add class to session cart

}
else
{
  //Code to add pack to session cart
}
```

**The strange thing**

No matter whether I pass true/false (by calling addClassToCart() and addPackToCart()), always the code to add class to session cart executes.
If I put echo statements there like this:-

```
    if($_POST['isClass'])
    {
      echo "see if condition ".$_POST['isClass'];
    }
    else
    {
      echo "see else condition ".$_POST['isClass'];
    }
```

This is the output:-

addClassToCart()    `see if condition true`
addPackToCart()     `see if condition false`

Putting conditions like this in the jquery code however works fine:-

```
function addItemToCart(itemId,isClass)
 {  
     if(isClass)
        alert("is class");
     else
        alert("is pack");
 }
```

Finally, if I alter the server side code to this:-

```
if($_POST['isClass'] === true)
        {
          echo "see if condition ".$_POST['isClass'];
        }
        else
        {
          echo "see else condition ".$_POST['isClass'];
        }
```

These are the outputs -

addClassToCart()    `see else condition true`
addPackToCart()     `see else condition false`

So, why is the boolean variable treated as a string here? Am I doing something wrong in posting parameters?

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Comment: That is definitely *not* unexpected. Everything passed via `GET` or `POST` to PHP are strings.

Comment: yes I see now... edited my question title

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong per se, it's just that when it gets posted, it looks like this:

```
operation=add_cart&isClass=true&itemId=1234
```

PHP can't tell what the data type is because it isn't passed, it's always just a string of POST data, so compare it to `"true"` to do your checks, like this:

```
if($_POST['isClass'] === "true")
{
  //Code to add class to session cart
}
else
{
  //Code to add pack to session cart
}
```

Comment: So is there no other way around? I prefer doing boolean checks as much as possible.

Comment: @sandeepan - nope, not sure what else to say other than...this is how http gets and posts work, it's perfectly normal.

Comment: Why not instead use '==' and let it do type conversion for you?

Comment: @Gary - Because it's a string , "false" is still true because it's a non-zero length string...be explicit and you won't get surprises.  The same rules apply to JavaScript for example, some people never use `==` and *only* use `===` for good reason.

Comment: I guess I had a misconception of type conversion.  Thanks Nick.

Comment: you can type cast it to a boolean like so `$foo = (bool) $_POST['foo'];`

Comment: @r3wt You would need to explicitly test for `'true'` and `'false'` and reset those values to booleans. The string `'false'` cast as a boolean will be true. Check out http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php to review how PHP converts such values.

Answer (score 83):

Also you can use filter_var function with filter FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN. According to php documentation it

> Returns TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns FALSE otherwise. If FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is set, FALSE is returned only for "0", "false", "off", "no", and "", and NULL is returned for all non-boolean values.

So receiving of POST parameter will look like:

```
$isClass = filter_var($_POST['isClass'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: +1 for `filter_var`, one of the often overlooked parts of the PHP.

Comment: Beautiful! Validating a boolean like it were a string is imho ugly and fubar.

Comment: Although I voted up the top three answers this was the one that was so clean and elegant, it made it into my code. Well done.

Comment: The best solution for retrieving the data in Ajax or Api.

Comment: Please get rid of the space between `filter_var` and its parentheses, it makes the code  only slightly harder to read but unimaginably disrupting to my internal peace and the system won't let me make such a minor edit. 

Comment: @HashimAziz done! Hope it brought internal peace to you :)

Comment: @Tamara If only, but close enough. Haha thanks

Comment: In case if `$_POST['isClass']` hasn't been passed at all (ie `$_POST['isClass']` is `NULL`), `filter_var($_POST['isClass'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` will return `false` as well.

Answer (score 20):

This is a bit of an old question, but I'm surprised nobody has posted this here as solution.

Just use 1 and 0 instead of true and false when you're constructing your ajax requests.
When you do a `==` comparison, they'll be interpreted as true/false.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '....',
  data: {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 0
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if ($_GET['foo']) {
     //...
  } else {
     //...
  }

  echo $_GET['bar'] ? 'bar is true' : 'bar is false';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the data from your javascript as stringified JSON.
2. Make a PHP function to convert the strings 'true' and 'false' to boolean value.

Personally I like #2, which goes with Nick Craver's answer.

Comment: number 1 works far better when the object you want to save is multi-leveled.. no ugly recursive php functions required just json_decode