# send data as Boolean from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending data from jquery to php using ajax but the problem is that whenever i send Boolean data through jquery php recieved it as a string. but i want Boolean data as Boolean not as a string

this is the code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updaterecord.php",
    data: { id:i, table:t, field:f, data: d },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(s){
       alert("Saved Successfully ");
    },
    error:function(e){
       alert("Error ");
    }
});
```

now if i send true on php side i get true as a string not as a Boolean value.is there any way to send Boolean data as Boolean

Comment: POST or GET HTTP request will always send text. You have to parse it on the other side.

Comment: I dont think jquery ajax has functionality to specify the data type of the data being passed to remote server script. you can just send `true` or `false` in ajax call and compare the string at server script side to check whether its true value or false

Comment: you can check in php if($_POST['YOUR_VARIABLE']=="true"){ //write code for true}else{//write code for false}

Comment: See answers in a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716730/send-a-boolean-value-in-jquery-ajax-data

Answer (score 0):

Just send 1 or 0 (true or false) and don't bother with type casting.