# Cannot obtain correct Boolean value when sent in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, boolean

let's say we have the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'myURL.php',
    data:{
        ac:'do',
        isDoable:false
    }
});
```

Now at the back end when reading the call data, the `isDoable` is a string, and trying to cast it as Boolean:

```
$isDoable = (bool) $_REQUEST['isDoable'];
```

results in `$isDoable` always being `true`, even when sent as `false`.
When I encountered this issue I gave up and simply treated it as a string `if($_REQUEST['isDoable'] == 'true')`

But I cannot get over it! why is this unexpected behavior, and is there a way around it?

Comment: How to convert string to boolean in php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336861/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-php

Comment: do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, and you'll see EXACTLY what's coming in. if JS is encoding that true as the literal string `'false'`, then a non-empty string will always evaluate as boolean `true` in php.

Comment: A query string is always a string and always has the format of  `http://somedomain.com/ourpage?key=value`. No mater you use JavaScript boolean. Technically its just a string as long as its a query string request. You are using $ajax with Get method.Hence its obviously treated as string. What you do is exactly the right method.

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654454/boolean-variables-posted-through-ajax-being-treated-as-strings-in-server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not sending a JSON data via POST (that could be handle correctly with the `json_decode`) your string `"true"` or `"false"` will always be the boolean `true`, because PHP will assume that, as a non empty string, your var should be converted to the `true` boolean value.

So, you should use string comparison instead in your case.

In example:

```
$value = (bool)"test"; // whatever value, not empty string
var_dump($value);
```

is the boolean `true`

```
$value = (bool)"";
var_dump($value);
```

is the boolean `false`